# Zonal Statistics not Working Properly in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have two rasters, one that describes different zones of the world and a second one which is the input raster that has continuous values for a variable.

I am using the Zonal Statistics tool to compute the sum of the values in the input raster aggregated at the level of the Zone Raster. Nevertheless, it is not working properly.

From my reading of the Esri forum and other posts the usual problem is that the input cells do not have any centers within a zone.

However, this is not the case in my problem. As you can see in the picture below, the different zones defined by my feature zone raster have this gray border and my input raster contains values that are being showcased in a yellow to blue scale.

The black zones are the ones computed by using the Zonal Statistics tool as a sum of all the values of each cell within the zone. Clearly, the tool is missing many different features that have a lot of cells inside.

[image: Fig 1.]

I am new to ArcGIS Desktop and at this point I am only using point and click commands.

Comment: I do not have access to Arc, but I believe your zone layer must be a vector (.shp). The shapefile defines boundaries whereas the raster is holding the information that will be put in those boundaries.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I convert my polygons to rasters and resample the input vector and still have the same problem.

Comment: No, you should not convert your polygons to rasters. Your polygon should be your zone, while your raster is your input.

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension with ArcGIS Pro or with ArcMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use zonal statistics from Spatial Analyst tools. With this tool you define 2 inputs:

1. Raster or Shapefile containing the zone
2. Raster with the values.

Simple tutorial:

https://youtu.be/HO1jNZitQBI